# Why does my app Size and Current Version "Varies with device" though I only uploaded one APK?

Tags: android

I just uploaded my android app for beta testing for the first time and my friends are able to download it without issue. However I found that in the app page, 'Size' and 'Current Version' shows 'Varies with device' instead of the actual apk size and version..

I've only uploaded only one APK, what gives?

Screenshot below:
[image]

If you wish to access my beta testing app page, send me a message with your gmail address in, so I can add you into the beta testing list.

Comment: No one knows? I'm still having this problem till this date..

Comment: Any luck so far, yet?

Comment: Does your new version have maps v2 integrated. if yes, that could be it, as it requires open gl 2.0 and not all devices support it.

Comment: It doesn't have maps v2 integrated

Comment: I downloaded The Dark Knight Rises game from play store from Samsung e5 with 990mb. Now from note 3 neo page shows the size as 2 gb !am not sure if page is just updated or size varies with os version .

Answer (score 12):

Have you found out the answer yet? Since you have not elected an answer as a correct one, here we go...

Google Play allows you to publish different APKs for your application. Each one targeted to different device configuration. Thus, each APK is an independent version of your application, but they share the same application listing on Google Play and must share the same package name and be signed with the same release key.

Usually Android applications run on most compatible devices with a single APK, by supplying alternative resources for different configurations (e.g., different layouts for different screen sizes) and the Android system selects the appropriate resources for the device at runtime. But in a few cases, however, a single APK is unable to support all device configurations, because alternative resources make the APK file too big (greater than 50MB) or other technical challenges prevent a single APK from working on all devices.

And even though Google doesn't encourage developers to use this "multiple APK" feature, most Google apps use it: Google+, Google Chrome, Gmail, Google Maps, Google Search, Google Play Books, Google Play Movies & TV, Google Translate.

I hope I was helpful.

Comment: I've only uploaded one APK, thanks for taking the time to answer though :)

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with using GooglePlayServices in the app then?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Artifacts library section of Release Management in Google Play developer console, you should have just one active artifact for the your app release.

Answer (score 0):

My app was on closed track and the latest release wasn't showing until I **removed the draft APKs** in "Artifact library" and **uninstalled the app from all closed test devices**.